# Fortify for Desktop Applications, Ignore Web App Issues

Tags: java, fortify

I am running HP Fortify on a Java desktop application. The application does not have a web component, but many of the issues are specifically for web applications. Is there a way to disable this?

More details available on request. I don't know which details are needed.

Comment: Yes, You have to add filter

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your issue then select `Generate Filter` and select appropriate option then select `Create Filter` button in `HP Fortify`

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. I would only like issues to be reported if they apply to desktop applications.